# Incontinuous Quaternion Signals

Tags: r, quaternions, inertial-navigation

I'm using a BNO055 IMU and I sometimes see "jumps" in the quaternion signals during the movement. Is this normal? Here's a sample plot.[image: Sample Plot of the Bad (!) Quaternion Data]

The first plot is the scalar value and the rest are the three vector components.

I assumed this happens to Euler Angles but not in Quaternions. Is there something I'm missing?

```
0.4978  0.37885 0.65814 -0.41888
0.49774 0.37854 0.65778 -0.41986
0.49762 0.37842 0.65759 -0.42035
0.49878 0.37616 0.6582  -0.42017
0.49878 0.37561 0.65784 -0.42114
0.49872 0.37537 0.65765 -0.42175
0.49933 0.3736  0.65802 -0.42206
0.49902 0.37347 0.65753 -0.42328
0.49896 0.37335 0.65735 -0.42371
0.49921 0.37189 0.6579  -0.42383
0.49872 0.37164 0.65771 -0.42499
0.49841 0.37158 0.65784 -0.42517
0.49854 0.37042 0.65881 -0.42444
0.49792 0.37042 0.65936 -0.42444
0.4975  0.37048 0.65961 -0.42456
0.49768 0.36932 0.66034 -0.42413
0.49701 0.36957 0.66034 -0.42468
0.49664 0.36975 0.66022 -0.42511
0.49719 0.36823 0.66083 -0.42487
0.49658 0.36877 0.66028 -0.42596
0.49622 0.36908 0.65991 -0.42664
0.49683 0.3678  0.66034 -0.42645
0.49609 0.36841 0.65973 -0.42767
0.49573 0.36871 0.65948 -0.42822
0.49658 0.36713 0.66003 -0.42773
0.49591 0.36768 0.65948 -0.42889
0.49554 0.36798 0.65918 -0.4295
0.49658 0.36572 0.66016 -0.42877
0.49554 0.36639 0.65942 -0.43048
0.49493 0.36676 0.659   -0.43158
0.49426 0.36682 0.65857 -0.43292
0.49316 0.36774 0.65765 -0.43475
0.49274 0.36816 0.65723 -0.43555
0.49261 0.36768 0.65717 -0.43616
0.49188 0.3681  0.65662 -0.43744
0.49152 0.36829 0.65643 -0.43805
0.4917  0.36719 0.65662 -0.43842
0.49091 0.36749 0.65619 -0.43976
0.49048 0.36768 0.65594 -0.44043
0.4903  0.36707 0.65607 -0.44098
0.48956 0.36713 0.65582 -0.44208
0.48926 0.36707 0.65576 -0.44257
0.48944 0.36591 0.65619 -0.44263
0.48926 0.36542 0.65631 -0.44312
0.48914 0.36511 0.65649 -0.44324
0.48962 0.36328 0.65741 -0.44281
0.48956 0.3623  0.6579  -0.44293
0.48956 0.36176 0.6582  -0.44299
0.4903  0.35937 0.65936 -0.44238
0.48993 0.35846 0.65967 -0.44305
0.48969 0.35815 0.65979 -0.44348
0.4903  0.35614 0.66077 -0.44287
0.48975 0.35596 0.66095 -0.44336
0.48956 0.35583 0.66101 -0.44354
0.48999 0.35449 0.66168 -0.44312
0.48969 0.35437 0.66174 -0.4436
0.48944 0.35431 0.66174 -0.44385
0.48932 0.35382 0.66193 -0.44409
0.48907 0.35364 0.66199 -0.44446
0.48895 0.35358 0.66199 -0.44464
0.48914 0.35272 0.66211 -0.44482
0.48883 0.35284 0.66193 -0.44543
0.48865 0.35297 0.6618  -0.4458
0.48938 0.35162 0.66229 -0.44519
0.48914 0.35193 0.66205 -0.44562
0.48901 0.35205 0.66199 -0.44574
0.48993 0.35059 0.66278 -0.44476
0.48999 0.35028 0.66309 -0.44446
0.49011 0.3501  0.66321 -0.44427
0.49097 0.34845 0.66425 -0.44305
0.49103 0.34814 0.66467 -0.44263
0.49103 0.34802 0.66486 -0.44238
0.49133 0.34747 0.66553 -0.44153
0.49152 0.34711 0.66608 -0.4408
0.49164 0.34686 0.66638 -0.44037
0.49274 0.34515 0.66766 -0.43854
0.49286 0.34473 0.66827 -0.43781
0.49298 0.34448 0.66858 -0.43744
0.49408 0.34259 0.66998 -0.43549
0.49445 0.34204 0.67065 -0.43451
0.49457 0.34174 0.67102 -0.43402
0.49518 0.34064 0.67194 -0.43274
0.49536 0.34015 0.67249 -0.43213
0.49536 0.3399  0.67273 -0.43188
0.49652 0.33789 0.67395 -0.43024
0.49652 0.33771 0.67426 -0.42987
0.49652 0.33765 0.67438 -0.42969
0.49738 0.33612 0.67535 -0.42834
0.49738 0.336   0.67566 -0.42804
0.49744 0.33588 0.67572 -0.42792
0.49835 0.33429 0.6767  -0.42664
0.49829 0.33423 0.67688 -0.42645
0.49829 0.33423 0.67694 -0.42633
0.49902 0.33276 0.67767 -0.42542
0.4989  0.3327  0.67767 -0.4256
0.49878 0.3327  0.67767 -0.42572
0.49908 0.33197 0.6781  -0.42535
0.49884 0.33209 0.67798 -0.42572
0.49872 0.33221 0.67786 -0.4259
0.49847 0.33228 0.67786 -0.42615
0.49835 0.3324  0.67786 -0.42627
0.49817 0.33252 0.67773 -0.42664
0.4986  0.33179 0.67798 -0.42627
0.49847 0.33185 0.67786 -0.42651
0.49823 0.33191 0.67773 -0.42694
0.4986  0.33105 0.67804 -0.4267
0.49854 0.33112 0.67798 -0.42682
0.49835 0.3313  0.67773 -0.42725
0.49829 0.33112 0.67767 -0.42761
0.49811 0.33118 0.67755 -0.42792
0.49786 0.33118 0.67743 -0.42841
0.49872 0.32953 0.6781  -0.42761
0.49866 0.32947 0.67804 -0.4278
0.49847 0.32947 0.67804 -0.42804
0.49847 0.32922 0.6781  -0.4281
0.49847 0.32922 0.67816 -0.42816
0.49841 0.32898 0.67822 -0.4281
0.49957 0.32697 0.67914 -0.42694
0.49957 0.32684 0.6792  -0.42694
0.49957 0.3266  0.67938 -0.42682
0.50031 0.32544 0.67993 -0.4259
0.50037 0.32532 0.68005 -0.42578
0.50049 0.32495 0.6803  -0.4256
0.50159 0.32306 0.68121 -0.42426
0.50165 0.32288 0.68127 -0.42413
0.50183 0.32251 0.68146 -0.42401
0.50256 0.32129 0.68207 -0.4231
0.50262 0.32117 0.68213 -0.42303
0.50269 0.32092 0.68219 -0.42291
0.50281 0.3208  0.68213 -0.42297
0.50287 0.32074 0.68213 -0.42303
0.50293 0.32068 0.68201 -0.42322
0.50323 0.32019 0.68207 -0.4231
0.50323 0.32019 0.68195 -0.42328
0.50323 0.32025 0.68182 -0.42346
0.50385 0.31934 0.68213 -0.42291
0.50385 0.31934 0.68207 -0.42303
0.50391 0.31934 0.68188 -0.42322
0.50513 0.31738 0.68268 -0.42194
0.50519 0.31738 0.68262 -0.42206
0.50513 0.31744 0.6825  -0.42218
0.50537 0.31708 0.68262 -0.42206
0.50537 0.31714 0.68256 -0.42212
0.50543 0.31708 0.6825  -0.42212
0.50629 0.31567 0.68311 -0.4212
0.50629 0.31567 0.68311 -0.4212
0.50629 0.31567 0.68304 -0.4212
0.50684 0.31482 0.68347 -0.42059
0.50696 0.31458 0.68359 -0.42035
0.50702 0.31451 0.68365 -0.42029
0.50757 0.3136  0.68402 -0.41974
0.50757 0.3136  0.68396 -0.41974
0.50763 0.3136  0.68396 -0.41974
0.50806 0.31287 0.68427 -0.41925
0.50806 0.31281 0.68427 -0.41925
0.50812 0.31281 0.68427 -0.41931
0.50867 0.31183 0.68469 -0.41858
0.50873 0.31183 0.68469 -0.41858
0.50873 0.31183 0.68469 -0.41858
0.50916 0.31104 0.685   -0.41803
0.50922 0.31104 0.685   -0.41803
0.50922 0.31104 0.685   -0.41803
0.51013 0.30957 0.68561 -0.41699
0.51013 0.30957 0.68561 -0.41699
0.51013 0.30957 0.68561 -0.41699
0.51044 0.30902 0.68579 -0.41663
0.51044 0.30902 0.68579 -0.41669
0.51044 0.30902 0.68579 -0.41669
0.51111 0.30792 0.68628 -0.41589
0.51117 0.30792 0.68622 -0.41589
0.51135 0.30768 0.68628 -0.41577
0.51135 0.30768 0.68628 -0.41577
0.51135 0.30762 0.68622 -0.41583
0.51208 0.3064  0.68677 -0.41498
0.51208 0.3064  0.68677 -0.41498
0.51215 0.30627 0.68683 -0.41492
0.51312 0.30463 0.68756 -0.4137
0.51324 0.3045  0.68756 -0.41364
0.51324 0.3045  0.68756 -0.41364
0.51385 0.30341 0.68799 -0.4129
0.51392 0.30341 0.68799 -0.41296
0.51392 0.30334 0.68799 -0.41296
0.51428 0.3028  0.68811 -0.41266
0.51434 0.30273 0.68805 -0.41272
0.51483 0.302   0.68835 -0.41223
0.51483 0.302   0.68835 -0.41223
0.51483 0.30194 0.68835 -0.41229
0.51495 0.30176 0.68842 -0.41217
0.51501 0.3017  0.68835 -0.41217
0.51501 0.3017  0.68835 -0.41223
0.51526 0.30139 0.68842 -0.41211
0.51526 0.30133 0.68842 -0.41211
0.51526 0.30133 0.68835 -0.41211
0.51593 0.30023 0.68872 -0.41144
0.51593 0.30023 0.68872 -0.41144
0.51611 0.29999 0.68878 -0.41132
0.51617 0.29987 0.68872 -0.41144
0.51617 0.29993 0.6886  -0.41162
0.51691 0.29865 0.68903 -0.41095
0.51691 0.29858 0.68896 -0.41101
0.51691 0.29846 0.68896 -0.41113
0.51703 0.29834 0.68884 -0.41125
0.51715 0.29822 0.68872 -0.41138
0.51721 0.2981  0.68872 -0.41144
0.51746 0.29767 0.68878 -0.41138
0.51752 0.29742 0.68878 -0.41144
0.51746 0.29761 0.6886  -0.41174
0.51752 0.29761 0.68854 -0.4118
0.51752 0.29761 0.68854 -0.4118
0.51776 0.2973  0.68854 -0.41162
0.51776 0.2973  0.68854 -0.41162
0.51776 0.2973  0.68854 -0.41162
0.5177  0.29736 0.68848 -0.41174
0.5177  0.2973  0.68848 -0.4118
0.51776 0.29724 0.68842 -0.41187
0.51831 0.29633 0.68872 -0.41138
0.51837 0.29639 0.68866 -0.41144
0.51831 0.29639 0.68854 -0.41156
0.51874 0.29559 0.68884 -0.41119
0.51874 0.29547 0.68884 -0.41125
0.51892 0.29517 0.68878 -0.41125
0.51898 0.29504 0.68878 -0.41132
0.51923 0.2948  0.68854 -0.41156
0.51959 0.29443 0.68829 -0.4118
0.52008 0.2937  0.68835 -0.41156
0.52032 0.29352 0.68799 -0.41205
0.52032 0.2937  0.68726 -0.41315
0.52045 0.2937  0.68695 -0.41351
0.52051 0.29388 0.68616 -0.41455
0.52063 0.2937  0.68585 -0.41504
0.52112 0.29291 0.68518 -0.41608
0.52179 0.29218 0.68427 -0.41736
0.52252 0.29144 0.68317 -0.4187
0.52313 0.29077 0.68274 -0.41913
0.5238  0.29041 0.68152 -0.42053
0.52417 0.29016 0.68103 -0.42102
0.52472 0.28906 0.68085 -0.42133
0.52545 0.28772 0.68066 -0.42163
0.52637 0.28619 0.68048 -0.42187
0.52692 0.2854  0.68036 -0.42194
0.52808 0.28381 0.67999 -0.42212
0.5293  0.28247 0.67957 -0.42224
0.52997 0.2818  0.67926 -0.42224
0.53107 0.28058 0.67908 -0.422
0.53223 0.27924 0.67908 -0.42151
0.53296 0.27838 0.67902 -0.42126
0.53479 0.27637 0.67871 -0.42065
0.53583 0.27521 0.67853 -0.42035
0.53796 0.27264 0.67828 -0.41974
0.53998 0.27008 0.67816 -0.41907
0.54102 0.26874 0.67816 -0.41852
0.54321 0.26575 0.67834 -0.4173
0.54559 0.26257 0.67853 -0.41589
0.54687 0.26099 0.67853 -0.41522
0.54944 0.25824 0.6781  -0.41425
0.55151 0.25665 0.67694 -0.41437
0.55225 0.25641 0.67615 -0.41479
0.55341 0.25647 0.67456 -0.41583
0.55475 0.25623 0.67291 -0.41687
0.55554 0.25574 0.67224 -0.41718
0.55768 0.25403 0.67126 -0.41699
0.56042 0.25128 0.67096 -0.41547
0.56183 0.24976 0.67078 -0.41473
0.56439 0.24719 0.67017 -0.41382
0.56616 0.24554 0.66949 -0.41351
0.56683 0.24518 0.66901 -0.41357
0.56769 0.24554 0.6676  -0.41443
0.56818 0.24713 0.66547 -0.41626
0.56836 0.24817 0.66418 -0.41742
0.56854 0.25073 0.66156 -0.41974
0.56873 0.25354 0.65955 -0.42108
0.56891 0.25476 0.65875 -0.42126
0.5697  0.25684 0.65747 -0.42096
0.57098 0.25903 0.6557  -0.42065
0.57178 0.26038 0.65442 -0.42078
0.57239 0.26373 0.65234 -0.42102
0.57269 0.26721 0.65015 -0.42181
0.57275 0.26843 0.64923 -0.42236
0.57288 0.26941 0.64801 -0.42346
0.57306 0.26898 0.64758 -0.42413
0.57312 0.26855 0.64746 -0.42444
0.57184 0.27045 0.6463  -0.42676
0.57355 0.26825 0.64636 -0.42584
0.57391 0.26746 0.64661 -0.42542
0.57349 0.26819 0.64587 -0.42664
0.57361 0.2691  0.64459 -0.4278
0.57397 0.26953 0.64362 -0.42859
0.57294 0.27289 0.64032 -0.43274
0.573   0.27423 0.63849 -0.43457
0.573   0.27484 0.63757 -0.43542
0.5708  0.27911 0.6347  -0.43976
0.57092 0.27991 0.63336 -0.44098
0.57111 0.28027 0.63251 -0.44177
0.56897 0.28424 0.62958 -0.44623
0.56915 0.284   0.62891 -0.44708
0.56927 0.28369 0.62878 -0.44727
0.56726 0.28619 0.62744 -0.4502
0.56763 0.28564 0.62714 -0.45044
0.56805 0.28503 0.62701 -0.45044
0.5675  0.2854  0.6261  -0.45227
0.56848 0.28333 0.62604 -0.45239
0.56866 0.28247 0.62616 -0.45251
0.56769 0.28217 0.62659 -0.45337
0.56726 0.28119 0.6283  -0.45215
0.56708 0.2807  0.62885 -0.45184
0.56567 0.28143 0.62878 -0.45325
0.56604 0.27985 0.62964 -0.45251
0.56616 0.27917 0.63025 -0.45203
0.56543 0.27887 0.63123 -0.45172
0.56567 0.27686 0.63306 -0.45013
0.56598 0.27563 0.63379 -0.44946
0.5658  0.27448 0.6344  -0.44946
0.56628 0.2724  0.63611 -0.44781
0.56659 0.27118 0.63727 -0.44653
0.56708 0.26874 0.63953 -0.44403
0.56818 0.26556 0.64203 -0.44092
0.56873 0.2641  0.64325 -0.43933
0.56915 0.26257 0.64496 -0.43726
0.57025 0.26038 0.64691 -0.43414
0.57074 0.25952 0.64783 -0.43268
0.57086 0.25867 0.64954 -0.43048
0.57135 0.25714 0.65149 -0.4278
0.57159 0.25653 0.6524  -0.42651
0.57104 0.2569  0.65356 -0.42517
0.57129 0.25616 0.65564 -0.42206
0.57141 0.25586 0.65692 -0.4201
0.57159 0.25543 0.65936 -0.41626
0.5719  0.2547  0.66162 -0.41272
0.57196 0.25446 0.6626  -0.41119
0.57208 0.25403 0.66449 -0.40826
0.57214 0.25354 0.66687 -0.40454
0.57208 0.25342 0.66809 -0.40271
0.57062 0.25488 0.66968 -0.40125
0.56921 0.25592 0.67133 -0.39978
0.5683  0.25677 0.67206 -0.39935
0.56525 0.2616  0.67236 -0.40002
0.56299 0.26532 0.67297 -0.39978
0.56158 0.26733 0.67297 -0.40033
0.55786 0.27264 0.67212 -0.40338
0.55432 0.27722 0.67145 -0.40631
0.55249 0.27942 0.67126 -0.40759
0.54889 0.28461 0.66992 -0.41101
0.54651 0.2879  0.66919 -0.41315
0.5451  0.28949 0.66895 -0.41418
0.54254 0.29254 0.66864 -0.41595
0.54034 0.29553 0.66833 -0.41718
0.53931 0.29736 0.66791 -0.41791
0.53687 0.30176 0.66681 -0.41962
0.53387 0.30634 0.66577 -0.42175
0.5321  0.30859 0.66534 -0.42303
0.52856 0.31238 0.66473 -0.4256
0.52563 0.31519 0.66443 -0.42761
0.5246  0.31622 0.66443 -0.42816
0.52313 0.31769 0.66486 -0.42828
0.52216 0.31873 0.66565 -0.42743
0.52179 0.31909 0.6662  -0.42676
0.52112 0.31976 0.6673  -0.42529
0.52039 0.3205  0.66827 -0.42419
0.51996 0.32104 0.66852 -0.42389
0.51874 0.32245 0.66882 -0.42383
0.51733 0.32391 0.6687  -0.4245
0.51666 0.32471 0.66858 -0.42505
0.5152  0.32599 0.66833 -0.42609
0.51385 0.32715 0.66827 -0.42706
0.51324 0.32745 0.66833 -0.42743
0.51227 0.32776 0.6687  -0.4278
0.5116  0.32776 0.66925 -0.42767
0.51141 0.3277  0.66956 -0.42761
0.51093 0.32733 0.6701  -0.42743
0.51031 0.32709 0.67065 -0.42755
0.51001 0.32709 0.67084 -0.42773
0.50909 0.32733 0.67096 -0.42841
0.508   0.32782 0.6709  -0.42938
0.50745 0.32794 0.67084 -0.43005
0.50702 0.32733 0.67114 -0.43054
0.50604 0.32776 0.6712  -0.43127
0.50562 0.32794 0.67126 -0.43152
0.50586 0.32654 0.67224 -0.43079
0.50562 0.32642 0.67224 -0.43115
0.50537 0.32629 0.67242 -0.43127
0.50549 0.32495 0.67322 -0.43097
0.50488 0.32428 0.67389 -0.43109
0.50452 0.32391 0.67426 -0.43121
0.50439 0.32184 0.67542 -0.43109
0.50311 0.32098 0.67566 -0.43286
0.50238 0.32056 0.67554 -0.43414
0.50183 0.31818 0.67548 -0.43658
0.50055 0.31628 0.67438 -0.44116
0.49969 0.31531 0.67346 -0.44421
0.49823 0.31213 0.67163 -0.45087
0.49438 0.31024 0.66888 -0.46033
0.49249 0.30884 0.66748 -0.46533
0.48987 0.3031  0.66595 -0.47394
0.48523 0.29797 0.66522 -0.48297
0.48248 0.29517 0.66498 -0.48773
0.47675 0.28815 0.66461 -0.49799
0.46942 0.28113 0.66376 -0.50995
0.46552 0.27704 0.66351 -0.51599
0.45862 0.26611 0.66443 -0.52661
0.45184 0.25269 0.66528 -0.53796
0.44836 0.24542 0.66553 -0.54382
0.44214 0.23041 0.66595 -0.55487
0.43695 0.21545 0.66516 -0.56586
0.43469 0.20819 0.66406 -0.57159
0.43048 0.19226 0.66223 -0.5824
0.42621 0.1734  0.6618  -0.59186
0.42346 0.16333 0.66248 -0.59595
0.41821 0.14209 0.66461 -0.60266
0.41278 0.11896 0.66742 -0.60834
0.40973 0.10706 0.66864 -0.61127
0.4032  0.08392 0.67041 -0.61719
0.396   0.06049 0.67145 -0.62341
0.39233 0.04865 0.67187 -0.62628
0.38403 0.02545 0.67358 -0.63098
0.37476 0.00323 0.67542 -0.63513
0.37018 -0.00739    0.67584 -0.63733
0.36084 -0.02777    0.67633 -0.64154
0.3512  -0.04767    0.67682 -0.6452
0.34644 -0.05725    0.67688 -0.64691
0.33783 -0.07623    0.67627 -0.65015
0.32916 -0.09412    0.6756  -0.65295
0.32483 -0.10278    0.67523 -0.65417
0.31628 -0.11951    0.67438 -0.65643
0.30859 -0.13525    0.67346 -0.65796
0.30524 -0.14301    0.67303 -0.65839
0.29883 -0.15735    0.67212 -0.65894
0.29285 -0.17017    0.67084 -0.65973
0.29016 -0.17627    0.67004 -0.6601
0.28577 -0.18774    0.66852 -0.66046
0.28168 -0.19818    0.6673  -0.6604
0.2796  -0.20319    0.66681 -0.66022
0.27612 -0.21216    0.66632 -0.65936
0.27332 -0.21948    0.66602 -0.65845
0.27197 -0.22217    0.66595 -0.65814
0.26971 -0.22528    0.66638 -0.65759
0.26965 -0.2262 0.66724 -0.65643
0.27045 -0.22577    0.66772 -0.65576
0.27319 -0.22284    0.66895 -0.65442
0.27765 -0.21875    0.67047 -0.65234
0.28021 -0.216  0.6712  -0.65137
0.28564 -0.20801    0.67273 -0.65009
0.29242 -0.19879    0.67462 -0.64801
0.29602 -0.19415    0.6756  -0.64667
0.30304 -0.18378    0.67767 -0.64435
0.31012 -0.17163    0.67938 -0.64252
0.31396 -0.16516    0.67981 -0.64191
0.32214 -0.15137    0.68018 -0.64081
0.33002 -0.13611    0.68066 -0.63971
0.33392 -0.12799    0.68103 -0.63898
0.34253 -0.11212    0.68109 -0.63739
0.35144 -0.0957 0.6795  -0.6369
0.35565 -0.0871 0.67853 -0.63678
0.36462 -0.06873    0.67621 -0.63641
0.37415 -0.05145    0.6734  -0.63556
0.37714 -0.04175    0.67322 -0.6347
0.38361 -0.02252    0.67169 -0.63336
0.3913  -0.0036 0.66858 -0.63239
0.39618 0.0047  0.66656 -0.63141
0.40436 0.02069 0.66473 -0.62781
0.40839 0.04364 0.66541 -0.62329
0.40979 0.05762 0.66559 -0.62103
0.41833 0.08002 0.66089 -0.61792
0.42279 0.09088 0.65839 -0.61603
0.42828 0.11566 0.65662 -0.60992
0.42963 0.14301 0.65747 -0.60223
0.42999 0.1557  0.65765 -0.59863
0.43103 0.17578 0.65833 -0.59155
0.43188 0.19214 0.66113 -0.58264
0.43396 0.19739 0.6629  -0.57733
0.44061 0.20557 0.66614 -0.56561
0.44531 0.21387 0.66895 -0.55536
0.44952 0.2215  0.6712  -0.54626
0.45117 0.22516 0.6723  -0.54199
0.45361 0.23413 0.67395 -0.53406
0.45398 0.23975 0.67493 -0.52997
0.45251 0.25287 0.67804 -0.52112
0.4516  0.26282 0.68158 -0.51227
0.45349 0.2652  0.68262 -0.508
0.45825 0.26947 0.68335 -0.50043
0.46191 0.27368 0.68396 -0.49396
0.46289 0.27582 0.68439 -0.49121
0.46259 0.28119 0.68542 -0.48694
0.46167 0.2887  0.68579 -0.48291
0.46191 0.29266 0.68524 -0.48108
0.46417 0.29999 0.68231 -0.47858
0.46539 0.30841 0.67859 -0.47729
0.46466 0.31329 0.67706 -0.47693
0.46198 0.32349 0.67401 -0.47711
0.46185 0.32941 0.6712  -0.47711
0.46277 0.33087 0.67059 -0.47614
0.46405 0.33325 0.67102 -0.4726
0.46539 0.33508 0.67358 -0.46625
0.46698 0.33557 0.67523 -0.46191
0.47168 0.33514 0.67834 -0.45276
0.47717 0.33417 0.67969 -0.44568
0.47937 0.33356 0.68011 -0.44318
0.48199 0.33136 0.68127 -0.44019
0.48431 0.32794 0.68188 -0.43927
0.48547 0.32648 0.68182 -0.43921
0.4873  0.32458 0.68134 -0.43921
0.48773 0.32434 0.68109 -0.43939
0.48767 0.32446 0.68085 -0.4397
0.48846 0.32416 0.68005 -0.44025
0.48926 0.32361 0.67963 -0.44049
0.48975 0.32312 0.6795  -0.44043
0.49103 0.32172 0.67944 -0.44019
0.49237 0.32007 0.67926 -0.44012
0.49292 0.31934 0.67914 -0.44025
0.49414 0.31812 0.67834 -0.44104
0.49463 0.31793 0.67725 -0.4422
0.49487 0.31805 0.6767  -0.44275
0.49548 0.31818 0.6756  -0.4436
0.49634 0.31781 0.67487 -0.44415
0.49689 0.31726 0.67462 -0.44421
0.49805 0.31561 0.67462 -0.44403
0.49921 0.31378 0.6748  -0.44379
0.49988 0.31293 0.67487 -0.4436
0.50128 0.31134 0.6748  -0.44324
0.50238 0.31042 0.67444 -0.44318
0.50281 0.31012 0.67426 -0.44318
0.50348 0.30969 0.67389 -0.44324
0.50397 0.30939 0.67352 -0.44354
0.50415 0.3092  0.67334 -0.44373
0.50458 0.30896 0.67273 -0.44427
0.50531 0.30853 0.67187 -0.44501
0.50568 0.30835 0.67163 -0.44513
0.50665 0.30762 0.67084 -0.44574
0.50751 0.30713 0.66956 -0.44702
0.50793 0.30707 0.66858 -0.44806
0.50867 0.30731 0.66608 -0.45074
0.50909 0.30829 0.66278 -0.45441
0.50934 0.30872 0.66083 -0.45667
0.51007 0.30908 0.65643 -0.46198
0.51038 0.30896 0.65222 -0.46765
0.51031 0.30878 0.65045 -0.47028
0.5105  0.30786 0.64771 -0.47449
0.51129 0.30621 0.64624 -0.47662
0.51196 0.30518 0.646   -0.47693
0.51349 0.30286 0.6463  -0.47632
0.51569 0.29968 0.64752 -0.4743
0.51691 0.29779 0.64844 -0.4729
0.51953 0.29352 0.65094 -0.4693
0.52081 0.29114 0.65253 -0.4671
0.52386 0.2854  0.65594 -0.46246
0.52765 0.2793  0.65869 -0.45801
0.5296  0.27655 0.65936 -0.45636
0.53345 0.27191 0.65955 -0.45441
0.53693 0.26782 0.65869 -0.45392
0.53857 0.26581 0.65796 -0.45435
0.54034 0.26263 0.6571  -0.45526
0.54236 0.26007 0.65692 -0.45453
0.54352 0.25946 0.65674 -0.45386
0.54492 0.26013 0.65503 -0.45422
0.5448  0.26294 0.65216 -0.45685
0.54395 0.26538 0.65045 -0.45892
0.54181 0.2713  0.64679 -0.46313
0.5401  0.27765 0.64331 -0.46619
0.53973 0.28064 0.64154 -0.46722
0.53998 0.2865  0.63739 -0.46912
0.53943 0.29291 0.63324 -0.47137
0.53857 0.29663 0.63116 -0.4729
0.53644 0.30487 0.62622 -0.4765
0.53375 0.31268 0.62103 -0.48126
0.53174 0.31659 0.61926 -0.48328
0.52832 0.32239 0.61633 -0.48694
0.52606 0.32477 0.61389 -0.49084
0.52527 0.32562 0.61298 -0.49231
0.52478 0.32556 0.61182 -0.49432
0.52557 0.3244  0.61115 -0.49506
0.52643 0.32336 0.61121 -0.49469
0.52979 0.32007 0.6106  -0.49402
0.53363 0.31647 0.60901 -0.49414
0.53546 0.31506 0.60791 -0.49445
0.53809 0.31287 0.6059  -0.49542
0.53998 0.31116 0.60388 -0.49695
0.54065 0.31055 0.60284 -0.4978
0.54126 0.31018 0.60059 -0.50012
0.54132 0.31097 0.59772 -0.50299
0.5412  0.31158 0.5965  -0.50427
0.54089 0.31238 0.59497 -0.5058
0.54059 0.31262 0.59424 -0.50684
0.54053 0.31268 0.59393 -0.5072
0.54102 0.31238 0.59332 -0.50769
0.54187 0.31134 0.59344 -0.50726
0.54242 0.31055 0.59369 -0.5069
0.54327 0.3092  0.59387 -0.50653
0.54382 0.3078  0.59467 -0.50586
0.54407 0.30707 0.59546 -0.50513
0.54456 0.30591 0.59686 -0.50366
0.54474 0.30518 0.59827 -0.5022
0.54468 0.30505 0.59924 -0.50122
0.54431 0.30499 0.60114 -0.49933
0.54395 0.3053  0.6026  -0.4978
0.54382 0.30542 0.60333 -0.49701
0.54352 0.30518 0.60541 -0.49493
0.5434  0.30499 0.60779 -0.49219
0.54352 0.30481 0.60889 -0.49084
0.54382 0.30444 0.61047 -0.48883
0.54395 0.30396 0.61163 -0.48755
0.54395 0.30383 0.6123  -0.48669
0.54431 0.30328 0.61456 -0.48376
0.54456 0.3028  0.61694 -0.48083
0.54449 0.3028  0.61761 -0.47992
0.54456 0.30292 0.61847 -0.47876
0.54456 0.30292 0.6192  -0.47772
0.54431 0.30273 0.62177 -0.47485
0.54413 0.3028  0.62378 -0.47235
0.54437 0.30267 0.62445 -0.47131
0.54523 0.30194 0.62592 -0.46881
0.54602 0.30078 0.62866 -0.46497
0.5462  0.30011 0.63055 -0.46265
0.54669 0.29919 0.63403 -0.45782
0.54767 0.29803 0.63696 -0.45343
0.5481  0.29718 0.63843 -0.45129
0.54889 0.29541 0.64142 -0.44727
0.54907 0.29413 0.64478 -0.44305
0.54895 0.29395 0.6463  -0.4411
0.54846 0.29443 0.6485  -0.43811
0.54724 0.29608 0.65027 -0.43591
0.54657 0.29706 0.651   -0.435
0.54523 0.29938 0.6521  -0.43341
0.54327 0.3017  0.65265 -0.43347
0.54144 0.30365 0.6535  -0.43317
0.53717 0.30774 0.65515 -0.43298
0.53357 0.31134 0.65625 -0.43329
0.53217 0.31281 0.65668 -0.43323
0.52972 0.31543 0.65796 -0.43243
0.52795 0.31738 0.65924 -0.43115
0.52722 0.31805 0.65997 -0.43048
0.52612 0.31873 0.66138 -0.42926
0.52545 0.3186  0.6626  -0.42822
0.52527 0.31836 0.66321 -0.42761
0.5249  0.31769 0.66467 -0.42633
0.52429 0.31726 0.66595 -0.42542
0.5238  0.31732 0.66644 -0.42523
0.52258 0.31763 0.66693 -0.4256
0.52136 0.31812 0.66742 -0.42609
0.52081 0.31836 0.66766 -0.42609
0.5199  0.31879 0.66864 -0.42542
0.5188  0.31927 0.66962 -0.4248
0.51819 0.31964 0.67004 -0.42474
0.51691 0.32043 0.67041 -0.42511
0.5155  0.32196 0.67017 -0.42603
0.51465 0.323   0.66992 -0.42664
0.51276 0.32538 0.66931 -0.42804
0.51068 0.32758 0.66882 -0.42957
0.50964 0.32849 0.66876 -0.4303
0.50793 0.32996 0.66876 -0.43115
0.50677 0.33093 0.66895 -0.43152
0.50629 0.33136 0.66907 -0.43158
0.50537 0.33209 0.66937 -0.43158
0.50452 0.33276 0.6698  -0.43146
0.50409 0.33307 0.66998 -0.43134
0.50336 0.3335  0.67059 -0.43091
```

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with that IMU, but it does look like it is hitting some internal limits.  Check your IMU manual.  Then tell us which R package you are using and give us a sample of your data so we can re-create what you are seeing.

Comment: You might also get better help here: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is normal, Quaternion keep rotation as angle in -pi to pi, so you see overflows of this limits

Comment: I included some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

As @minorlogic also wrote in their comment, these jumps occur near the circular limits of `(0,2pi]` or `(-pi,pi]` -- or, in terms of unit quaternions (being constructed as `[cos(phi), sin(phi) * rotAxis]`), more appropriately in the range `(-1,1]` for each component.

Most IMUs however don't represent their orientation readings in a normalised fashion, though, but the normalisation factor(s) should be stated in the data sheet (as @daniel-wisehart mentioned in their comment). When applying these factors, you should obtain a quaternion representation with values between -1 and 1. These overflows will still be present, though, as these are basically a normalisation requirement (i.e. to keep the *unit* part of unit quaternions).